# Getting number of unique values for time period based on previous data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `country` table with `id`, `country_uuid`, `visited`, `arrival` columns.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE `country` (
  `id` serial primary key,
  `country_uuid` varchar(191) NOT NULL,
  `visited` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `arrival` DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO country (country_uuid, visited, arrival) VALUES 
('abc', null, "2019.01.01"),
('abc', 'yes',"2019.01.02"),
('cba', 'no', "2019.01.03"),
('def', 'yes',"2019.01.04"),
('def', 'yes',"2019.01.04"),
('cba', 'yes',"2019.01.04"),
('abc', 'yes',"2019.01.05");
```

I need an mySQL query that for example for time period from 2019.01.03 to 2019.01.06 will **return 1**, based on `visited = yes`, but not listed `visited = yes` for period before 2019.01.03. So, 1 is return because only cba was visited once, but even though abc for the time period is also visited once, it was visited before 2019.01.03 on 2019.01.02.

def is not counted as it is visited twice during time period.

In the the end, as I mentioned I need to see like:

```
unique_country_uuid_count
1
```

I don't know even how to wrap my head around it. I used distinct for the time period, but how to exclude based on previous data, I don't know.

I am not even sure the code I made is correct, but I tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    con.country_uuid, 
    con.visited AS visited, 
    con.arrival AS arrival
FROM country con
WHERE 
    (arrival BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW()) AND 
    visited IS NOT NULL AND
    visited='yes' ;
```

link to [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/378f1)

SOLUTION:

First I ended up using @Alberto Moro solution, but then adopted @Strawberry way as more efficient:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM country con1
LEFT JOIN country con2 ON con1.country_uuid = con2.country_uuid 
   AND con2.arrival < con1.arrival 
   AND con2.visited IN ('yes', 'no')
WHERE con1.visited = 'yes'
    AND con1.arrival BETWEEN '2019-01-03' AND '2019-01-06'
    AND con2.id IS NULL;
```

Thanks for help or hint in advance.

Comment: Can you show us your attempts? what you've tried so far?

Comment: _Specify_ the expected result as well.

Comment: Store dates using a correct date data type. And see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: And note that DISTINCT is not a function

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ yes, did it.

Comment: @jarlh yes, edited.

Comment: @Strawberry made link to sqlfiddle.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is **not a function**, it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` and works on the whole selected rows. Skip those extra parentheses and simply write `SELECT 
        DISTINCT country_uuid, 
        con.visited AS visited, 
        con.arrival AS arrival ...` to make the code much less confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT x.country_uuid
     , COUNT(*) total
  FROM country x
  LEFT
  JOIN country y
    ON y.country_uuid = x.country_uuid
   AND y.visited = 'yes'
   AND y.arrival < '2019-01-03'
 WHERE x.visited = 'yes'
   AND x.arrival BETWEEN '2019-01-03' AND '2019-01-06'
   AND y.id IS NULL
 GROUP
    BY x.country_uuid;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example in my opinion does not include all cases. However I wrote this:

```
SELECT country_uuid, 
       count(country_uuid) AS unique_country_uuid_count
FROM country
WHERE visited = "yes"
AND country.country_uuid IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT c2.country_uuid
    FROM country c2
    WHERE c2.arrival BETWEEN '2019-01-03' AND '2019-01-06'
)
GROUP BY country_uuid
HAVING count(country_uuid) = 1
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/58e213/12)

Comment: Is there a way to avoid full table scan or this is as efficient as it can get for such a query?